# How to monitor the emails triggered from SharePoint?

Tags: email, sharepoint-email

I need to monitor all the emails triggered from SharePoint. Due to some restrictions by the policy I can not use local SMTP for sending emails. And it is using mail hub/mail server for sending emails. I need to monitor all the emails sent from my SharePoint server, either a notification/alert, workflow or permission related emails. Is it possible to track ? or what would be the best solution to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do not use the LOG or write some information to a list?

Comment: SharePoint ULS Log's doesn't store this information :( I'm not sure of verbose logging. Is there any tool available that can be purchased ?

Comment: you can write a "custom" log entry

Comment: But where exactly or for which condition ?

Comment: just log after the line that send email, use a try-cath for the exception

Comment: I'm asking for default SharePoint emails not for the custom one. In Custom solution I'can capture the email log.